# A serif font for MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, design

Wouldn't it be nicer to have a serif font on MathOverflow? As is done, say, on **[MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)**. 
It seems to be much more readable, like a printed text. And I'd say making answers looking more like notes or even articles :)

Comment: Sans serif is great. And it's much like the previous version of MO. No need to change it all of a sudden.

Comment: I have posted two answers as a poll. Please only vote up the answer you agree with, or contribute another option if you think otherwise. My vote is for keeping the sans serif font.

Comment: I'm not in favour of any further changes to the MO look, but the OP is absolutely right that serif fonts are more readable.

Comment: I'm certainly in favour of doing a site redesign, but _not yet_. We have lots of little problems to iron out, and we also want to get everyone used to the new software.

Comment: *Which* serif fonts? Baskerville? Palatino? TNR? etc etc

Comment: I am afraid that a debate about which font/typeface is most readable is likely to not lead us very far. It seems to be very much about personal preferences and habits. Also, note that on the web most pages use sans serif so many people will be more comfortable with that. On the other hand, you can probably set your browser to use a different font in some relevant dialog menu; most common browsers should support that. That seems like a much easier alternative course of action, if not as convenient for some.

Comment: $\mathfrak{I \; prefer \; Fraktur}$! :-)

Comment: If someone really wants a serif font they could probably override it with the Stylish Firefox extension.

Comment: The request has been declined by the community according to vote counts below.

Comment: Ill-designed fonts do not distinguish I and l.

Answer (score 39):

Please vote this answer up if you think MathOverflow should stay with a sans serif font (similar to the font on the original site).

*Please do not vote this answer down if you disagree with this.*

Comment: Voting for this because the sans serif font helps make a clear visual distinction between MathOverflow and math.stackexchange, which I think is quite useful now that they’re on the same network.

Answer (score 14):

Please vote this answer up if you think MathOverflow should switch to a serif font (similar to the one on MSE).

*Please do not vote this answer down if you disagree with this.*

Answer (score 7):

There is a third option besides staying with sans serif or switching to a serif font.

This other option is making this user-definable like it is for example in the documentation 
for the computer algebra system [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html) -- clicking on [Style](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chooser.html?BACK=http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html) takes one
to a menu where one can select one's preferred layout settings.